# Hands of a clock forming certain angles

Tags: arithmetic, recreational-mathematics

How many times to the hands of a clock form a 60 degree angle between noon and midnight on the same day?

Firstly im not sure weather they require the second hand to be included.

And secondly (excuse the pun) i have no clue how to start the problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Linear algebra and physics, maybe geometry would fit better

Comment: Think about how many times the hands of the clock cross between noon and midnight - how often does the minute hand catch up with the hour hand? And how many times do they make the angle you want between crossings.

Comment: It probably should have been more explicit: by hands they mean hour and minute.

Comment: Yeah, the second hand would be the third hand. Nevertheless, check carefully whether or not the problem statement wants you to count both $+60^\circ$ and $-60^\circ$ or just one.

Answer (score 1):

### Hint

Total angle swept by the pins on a clock $ = 360^{\ \text{o}} $

Smallest unit on clock (for recreational questions, second hand is **NOT** taken into consideration) $ = 1 $ minute

$ \therefore $ Area swept per minute $ \implies 6^{\text{ o}} $.

---

Hence, to generate an angle of $ 60^{\text{ o}} $ (between hour and minute hands), they should be $ 10 $ units apart.

Answer (score 1):

Think of the minute hand and hour hand as running around a circular racetrack.  The minute hand repeatedly passes the hour hand and loops around behind it.  This happens 11 times from noon to midnight.  So the question becomes: how many times is the distance along the track between the two hands 1/6 of the length of the track?

> For each time the minute hand "laps" the hour hand, there were two times in between where the angle between the hands was 60°.  The minute hand laps the hour hand 11 times from noon to midnight, so the hands form a 60° angle 22 times during that period.

Comment: Surely it happens 11 times (not counting noon and midnight)?

Comment: @TonyK Ack, you're right.  I'll fix that.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the minute hand starts in the same position as the hour hand. It catches up again a little after 1:00pm, between 1:00 and 2:00 (first); between 2:00 and 3:00 (second); between 3:00 and 4:00 (third); between 4:00 and 5:00 (fourth) ... between 10:00 and 11:00 (tenth) then catches up at 12:00 midnight (eleventh).

Between each pair of crossings, there are two occasions on which the angle is $60^{\circ}$.

Note that the $11$ crossings occur over $12$ hours and are hence $\cfrac {12}{11}$ hours apart - or one hour and $\cfrac {60}{11}$ minutes apart. The first $60^\circ$ crossing occurs one sixth of the time between crossings, $\cfrac 16\cdot \cfrac{12}{11}=\cfrac 2{11}$ hours after each crossing. The second is after five sixths of the time between crossings or $\cfrac {10}{11}$ hours since the last crossing.

Answer (score 0):

It takes 12 elevenths of an hour for phase relationships between the hour hand and minute hand to repeat (and 60 fifty-ninths of a minute for phase relationships between the minute hand and second hand to repeat).

We can call these phase relationships the "shapes of times". Since 10  o'clock and 2 o'clock are shapes with 60 degree leads (or lags) between hour and minute hands, there will be 22 instances of the 60 degree displacement (11 instances of the 2 o'clock shape, 11 instances of the 10 o'clock shape).

These times are easy to mentally picture (and calculate) as long as it's remembered that 12 elevenths of an hour is 1 hour, 5 and five elevenths minutes. It's not a major calculation: the 2 o'clock shape (and any other shape) will repeat 1 hour - five and 5 elevenths minutes later, 2 hours - ten and 10 elevenths minutes later, three hours - 15 and 15 elevenths minutes later, etc. This sequence goes round the dial until 11 hours, fifty-five and 55 elevenths minutes later - at which point we're 12 hours further along and the sequence starts again.

Happy clock watching!